# GAE - Ancestor issue

Tags: python, database, google-app-engine, transactional

I want to have unique values in my gae, so i read though the docs and found that "transactions" are atomic.

https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/transactions

```
class Account(ndb.Model):
    """"Required DB """
    username = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    password = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    mail = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    salt = ndb.StringProperty(required=True)
    date = ndb.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

    name  = ndb.StringProperty()
    last_name  = ndb.StringProperty()
    phone_number  = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    postal  = ndb.IntegerProperty()
    city  = ndb.StringProperty()

    products = ndb.IntegerProperty(repeated=True)

    @ndb.transactional
    def create_account(self):
         acc = Account.query(Account.username==self.username)
         acc = tuple(acc)
         if len(acc)== 0:
             self.put()
         else:
             #yield error
             pass
```

I awalys get the same error

> BadRequestError:
>
> Only ancestor queries are allowed inside transactions.

My db model "Account" does not have any ancestors.
Shouldn't it be the only "ancestor" ?

Comment: you make a query inside a transaction. your query don't have `ancestor`. the error seems to be consistent

Comment: So I'm not allowed to make a query inside a transaction ? Then I think  the only way that I know would be to put something on the memcache(I think memcache should be atomic too)

Comment: I don't have enough knowledge to adequately respond to your question but I have the same problem with my computedproperty(s): this make a query and return a simple sum. I had to remove all transactions
and put directly for continue the development. In your case try without the decorator.. we will have better answers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A way to circumvent this problem would be using the username as the key.

```
@classmethod
@ndb.transactional
def create(cls, username):
    key = ndb.Key('Account', username)
    existing_user = key.get()
    if existing_user:
        raise ValueError
    else:
        new_instance = cls(key=key, username=username)
        new_instance.put()
    return new_instance
```

Comment: Thanks. But can you explain to me what a key is ? What is the difference between a key and a query? i read though https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/entities but I am still confused

Comment: See https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/keyclass, it's the database key of the entity.